# How can I exchange an old pound coin in the UK?

Tags: uk, money

Since I haven't opened a bank account in the UK yet, this question should be valid for travellers as well. When a bus driver rejected the coin (£1) below, I noticed that it is out of circulation. As far as I understand, I could deposit it if I had an account.

What other options do I have without a bank account?

[image: old one pound]

Comment: That would make it a collectors item. I would keep it? Still a pawn shop should do the trick.

Comment: The photo is upside down.

Comment: @phoog Should be correct now. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Use it to pay in a supermarket or somewhere where automated tills are used

Comment: @Traveller in my experience with other coin changes, machines that take the new coins typically don't take the old ones.  Is it different with the pound coins in the UK?

Comment: if you're in London you can take it to the Bank of England. Otherwise you will need to have a certain bank account, if you have one you can just take it to a post office and they out it into your bank, you can try your luck at a high street bank too

Comment: At least according to https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/2018/08/almost-170-million-old-pounds-coins-still-in-circulation---heres-what-to-do-with-yours/ the bank of england only exchange banknotes not coins.

Comment: @BritishSam given the OP just got rejected by a bus driver for using an old quid, chances are they are not based near central London, hence the later options apply. OP can also mail the money (notes only, apparently) to the Bank of England (cost/benefit analysis advised), and some high street bank do take old notes/coins once you have an account with them as part of their service.

Comment: How many do you have? If just one then almost any solution is likely to cost more than the face value of the coin.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, just one. It can be better to keep it as Hanky Panky's point of view either.

Comment: When I had this problem I put the coin (actually two or three of them) in a collection bin for charity, hoping they would eventually have enough that it made it worth the effort for them.

Comment: `Unlike bank notes, UK coins are produced by the Royal Mint, who take no responsibility for coins that are no longer in circulation.

However, most banks have said that they will accept old pound coins indefinitely, though you will need to be a customer of that particular bank. If you take your coins in, they can either be exchanged for new ones or deposited into your bank account, and there is no minimum nor maximum number that can be exchanged at once.` https://www.simplybusiness.co.uk/knowledge/articles/2018/03/what-should-you-do-with-old-notes-and-coins/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bank of England](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/exchanging-old-banknotes)

> We do not exchange coins
>
> Please contact the Royal Mint for information about coins or to exchange coins

[The Royal Mint](https://www.royalmint.com/help/coinage-faqs/how-can-i-dispose-of-demonetised-coins/)

> How can I dispose of coins no longer in circulation?
>
> It is our understanding that some United Kingdom high-street banks are willing to accept demonetised coins from their customers. Please be aware, however, they are under no legal obligation to do so.

That seems to suggest that your coin is no longer a legal tender and a monetary exchange is not guaranteed.

**I would keep it as a souvenir.**

However, if you still like to sell your coin this may help:

> [Does the Royal Mint buy coins and medals from the general public?](https://www.royalmint.com/help/trm-faqs/buying-back-coins-and-medals/)
>
> The Royal Mint does not currently purchase old coins or medals.
>
> If you wish to sell your coins we would recommend that you contact a reputable coin dealer such as Sovereign Rarities Ltd. www.sovr.co.uk or your local BNTA member www.bnta.net

A very relevant news article: [How to swap your old £1 coin for a new one at your bank – when did they change and how long will banks accept the round pounds?](https://www.thesun.co.uk/money/4658600/old-pound-coins-swap-bank-exchange-bank-barclays-lloyds-hsbc-rbs-santander/)